# Covariance matrix of Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-optics, covariance, stochastic-processes, open-quantum-systems

Rewrite the Lindblad equation above into a Fokker-Planck equation for the Wigner function is:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial W}{\partial t}(x,p)=-\omega_0p\frac{\partial W}{\partial x} - \omega_0(Xg^2-1)x\frac{\partial W}{\partial p}+\kappa(2W+x_i\partial_iW + \partial_i\sigma^L_{ij}\partial_jW),\end{equation}

Here $x_1=x$, $x_2=p$, and
\begin{align}
\sigma^L =\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1+Xg^2\frac{\Gamma\omega_0}{\Omega\kappa}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
and in the original paper it says "Since this equation is quadratic in $x$ and $p$, it can be solved by a Gaussian ansatz $W=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi \text{det}(\sigma)}}\exp[\frac{-1}{2}\textbf{x}^T\sigma^{-1}\textbf{x}]$. The displacement decays at a rate $2\kappa$ and will quickly reach $0$. Thus, this function is entirely caracterised by the covariance matrix, which is described by the following equation:

\begin{align}
\partial_t\sigma & = B\sigma+\sigma B^T- 2\kappa(\sigma - \sigma^L)
\end{align}
With:
\begin{align*}
B & =\begin{bmatrix}0 & \omega_0\\ \omega_0(Xg^2-1) & 0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
I can't understand how to obtain the covariance matrix equation from the F-P equation, and in order to find the way of covariance matrix equation from there, I insert the expression of W into the F-P equation, but because exist $\sigma^{-1}$ in W, I cannot find the correct expression of covariance matrix. Maybe the way is incorrect.

How to understand about the covariance matrix equation is from F-P equation?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you present in more details (with equations) how you have approached this problem and where you get stuck?

Comment: i want obtain details derivation of Fokker-Planck equation to covariance matrix equation. Since this equation is quadratic in x and p, it can be solved by a Gaussian ansatz. so i substituted the expression $W=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi \text{det}(\sigma)}}\exp\[\frac{-1}{2}\textbf{x}^T\sigma^{-1}\textbf{x}]$ into Fokker-Planck equation. more details is below:

Comment: i'm sorry i don't know how to upload my manuscript. if o paste my tex code the comment characther show is tolong. this is my first use stackexchange. details prosses is I'm using $W=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi \text{det}(\sigma)}}\exp\{-\frac{1}{2}x_i(\sigma^{-1})_{ij}x_j\}$ instead of W(x,p) in F-P expression, then expand the equation for simply. because $\sigma^{-1}$ in partial , so I don't know how to proceed and whether this is the right thing to do.

Comment: The link to the original article is https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.00604v1, and the about content is appendix_IV. Dissipative dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you get stuck. Perhaps it is because $\sigma$ appears as an inverse in the exponent. In your ansatz, you need to give sigma a $t$-dependence. Then you can evaluate the derivative using the identity:
$$ \partial_t \sigma(t)^{-1} = -\sigma(t)^{-1}\cdot\left[\partial_t \sigma(t)\right]\cdot\sigma(t)^{-1} . $$
Then you can remove the inverse on both sides. The other derivatives should be easy. Hope that helps.

Comment: I am very grateful. because σ appears as an inverse in the exponent, and i don't know how to deal with it, now i could continue to derivation it. It would be nice if you could tell me where to find the source of this formula or how to get it. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It's easy to derive. Take the derivative of $\sigma^{-1}\cdot\sigma=1$ and apply $\sigma^{-1}$ at the back.

Comment: Thank you very much, i get it.